# How to write a maximize constraint using gurobipy

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm using gurobi on python and
I'd like to solve a route problem but there are some constraints I don't know how to write as in the picture:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bBK.png)

I have tried several ways,

*1st try*: `model.addConstr(a[j,k] == max_((b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M), 0) )`

*2nd try*: to use the indicator constraint separately like below

```
model.addConstr((c == 0) >> (b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M <= -eps) )
model.addConstr((c == 1) >> (b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M >= 0))
```

*3rd try*: `model.addGenConstrMax( a[j,k], [0, b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M]  )`
to run the code but didn't work every-time.

- note that M represents BigM and eps I set for is 1e-6
- a[] and b[] are continuous variables, x[] is a binary variable, and T_ij[] is a parameter

Comment: This is already answered in the [official Gurobi forums](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360074541152).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, copy of the answer from the [Gurobi Forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360074541152):

Your first try was almost successful. Please note that the `max_()` only accepts single Variables and constants as arguments but the term `(b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M)` is a `LinExpr`. Thus, in order to make your first approach work, you can add auxiliary variables for each of the terms as

```
N = [1,2,3]
V = [4,5,6]

a = m.addVars(N,V,name="a")
b = m.addVars(N,V,name="b")
T_ij = m.addVars(N,N,name="T_")
x = m.addVars(N,N,V,name="x")
aux = m.addVars(N,N,V,name="aux")
M = 10000

for i in N:
  for j in N:
    for k in V:
      m.addConstr(aux[i,j,k] == (b[i,k] + T_ij[i,j] - ( 1-x[i,j,k] )*M))
      m.addConstr(a[j,k] == max_( aux[i,j,k], 0) )
```

The same applies to your third approach because the `max_()` is just a shortcut for the `addGenConstrMax()` function.

Your 2nd approach should work as it is, but I would recommend using one of the
`max` functions.